# How do I take an item from an javascript array and transfer it to html in a paragraph tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an JS array `panier=["Crayon Crayola"]` and I want to put the item inside it into a paragraph tag `<p>Crayon Crayola</p>`. So how can I do this?

Comment: `document.querySelector("p").innerText = panier[0];`

Comment: Are you looking to create the entire `<p>` element, or just update the text of an existing one in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have only one element in the array then you can use this(you need to give the p tag an id):

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = panier[0];
```

if you want the whole array then use:

```
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = panier.toString();
```